# Class method returning class instance: how to avoid circular import errors when defining in seperate file?

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to find out, what options I have for moving a method definition to a different file from the class definition.

Example: I have a class, with a method that returns a new instance of the same class:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

class C1:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def added_to_val(self, to_add: float) -> C1:
        """Return new instance of class C1, with incremented value."""
        return C1(self.val + to_add)    

instA = C1(25)
instB = instA.added_to_val(2)
instB.val #27
```

Now I want to move `added_to_val` to another file (because it's actually a long function and things are getting hard to read), but that's not working.

Here's what I did:

```py
# file classdef.py
from __future__ import annotations
from .methoddef import _added_to_val

class C2:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    added_to_val = _added_to_val


# file methoddef.py
from .classdef import C2

def _added_to_val(instance: C2, to_add: float) -> C2:
    """Return new instance of class C2, with incremented value."""
    return C2(instance.val + to_add)
```

However, that gives an `ImportError: cannot import name '_added_to_val' from partially initialized module 'methoddef' (most likely due to a circular import)`.

Any ideas how to fix this? Or must class methods that return an instance of the same class always be located in the same file?

---

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize the method:

```
def _added_to_val(klass):
    """Return new instance of class C2, with incremented value."""
    def wrapped_added_to_val(instance: klass, to_add: float) -> klass:
        return klass(instance.val + to_add)
    return wrapped_added_to_val
```

and then use it like:

```
class C2:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def added_to_val(instance: C2, to_add: float) -> C2:
        return _added_to_val(C2)(instance, to_add)
```

Warning: I haven't tested this, especially type annotations might be wrong in the first snippet. Also I wish I named the functions better but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @loa_in_, that's a creative solution :) It seems there is still a problem, allbeit another one: I get a `NameError: name 'C2' is not defined` (in the line `added_to_val = _added_to_val(C2)`). The problem persists if I move the wrapper to the same file.

Comment: I could added the method after the fact with `C2.added_to_val = _added_to_val(C2)`. But combined with the additional layer of abstraction caused by the wrapper, it's getting more obfuscated than I'd be happy with.

Comment: I also thought of that... but recalculating the wrapper every time the function gets executed is a step in the wrong direction, I hope you agree. But I'll keep it as a solution of last resort ;)